# Jacoco classnotfound exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm using jacococ 0.8.7 version, maven 3.3.9 version, jDK 1.8 while I was running from Jenkins I'm facing below exception. what could be the issue? it worked when I used jacoco 0.7.4

command using in Jenkins:

```
 -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -U clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:prepare-agent org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:report test
```

Error

> Execution default-cli of goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:prepare-agent failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:prepare-agent: org/jacoco/core/runtime/AgentOptions

**pom.xml**

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: Could you provide your ```pom.xml``` file? Especially, the dependencies section.